# XYChart.Series.getData().clear() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

When I try to clear my collection (link to a lineChart), I have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. According to an another post I try to use a Platform.runlater but the problem continues. I was wondering if someone had the same problem and how to solve it?

```
public void loadFullData(){
  System.out.println("processing");
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() {
    data.getPeaksCol().getData().clear();
    data.getPeaksCol().getData().addAll(newData);
  }});
}
```

**EDIT :** 
The full stackTrace :

```
processing
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2036, Size: 2036
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series.getItem(XYChart.java:1628)
    at javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.dataItemRemoved(LineChart.java:305)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.dataItemsChanged(XYChart.java:497)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.access$2300(XYChart.java:93)
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1457)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:157)
    at graphModel.GraphModel$1.run(GraphModel.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1079803749.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of an exception.

Comment: Try to split your line as below and see which line throws the exception:

Object bla= data.getPeaksCol();

Object bla2= data.getPeaksCol().getData();

See which list is empty

Comment: Do you have any listener added to data observablelist? Can you try your code after disabling the anmiation of linechart.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir None of my list are empty. The problem is when I try to clear the collection, it's already used by an another thread.

Comment: I dont think so, clear method desn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsException...

Comment: @UlukBiy Yes I have some listeners, because this function allows the user to load full data on the chart, because initially only selected peaks (data) are visible. I keep the same Series to fill chart data.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I have 2036 Data<Number, Number> in my Series (peaksCol).

Comment: are you looping through array list index? and have `<=` instead of `<` ?

Comment: @Sendi_t I have no loop, I only call clear function on the collection. My loadFullData() function works but I'd like to solve the error.

Comment: @Thomas, try again after 1) disabling animation of linechart 2) disabling data list listeners.

Comment: @Thomas,  what does your `getData()` do? b/c based on your stacktrace neither `clear()` nor `addAll()` calls `RangeCheck()`

Comment: When is `loadFullData()` being called? Is it called from a listener of some kind?

Comment: @UlukBiy I tried to disable animation of the chart and it seems to solve the error. My function is triggered by a listener.

Comment: @Thomas, JavaFX charts do not support zooming by default.

Comment: @UlukBiy Yes I know, but I implement the jfxutils library which include a zoom function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error using the oracle's linechart tutorial and simply adding a button where on clicking removes all data of the only series. Seems like a bug of race condition due to animation of chart. The quick workaround is to disable animation while clearing all data:

```
lineChart.setAnimated(false);
series.getData().clear();
lineChart.setAnimated(true);
```

---

I think the bug is in code of `LineChart.dataItemRemoved(...)`:

```
if ( itemIndex > 0 && itemIndex < series.getDataSize() ) {
    animate = true;
    XYChart.Data<X, Y> p1 = series.getItem( itemIndex - 1 );
    XYChart.Data<X, Y> p2 = series.getItem( itemIndex + 1 );
    ...
    ...
}
```

if the `itemIndex = series.getDataSize() - 1` the line `series.getItem( itemIndex + 1 )` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I tried too and it works. Thank you for your time and your answer. By the way, is disabled the chart animation can occur somes issues with the user interactivity (zoom, etc)?

Comment: @Thomas, you can disable animation only when clearing data. See edit.

Comment: I have a chart that is not animated. Still get the Exception.